# PHP login not working. Using password_verify and it seems to be causing some problems

Tags: php, forms, mysqli, submit, password-hash

I am not sure why it won't work.

**Login.php**

```
$email = $_POST['email];
$password = $_POST['password];

$validEmail = filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);

$getpassword = $connect->query("SELECT password FROM users WHERE email = '$validEmail'");
$row = $getpassword->fetch_assoc();
```

All of the above works fine. I get the password which the email is connected to, so that I can "verify" the password.

```
$passVarify = password_varify($password, $row['password']);
```

When I try to "echo" out or use "var_dump" / "print_r" on "$passVerify", it just shows the number "1"?
After I have verified the password, I run another query, so that I can get the "userid" and "privileges". I needed to "unhash" or turn the password "normal" again, so that I could make the query below.

```
$result = $objConnection->query("SELECT userid, privileges FROM users WHERE email = '$validEmail' && password = '$passVarify'");
```

The code below doesn't seem to pick up the query? It just doesn't work for some reason.

```
if($result->num_rows > 0) {

    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

    $userid = $_SESSION['userid'] = $row['userid'];
    $privileges = $_SESSION['privileges'] = $row['privileges'];

}
```

Any good ideas? Cause I've been scratching the back of my head trying to figure out why the first "query" works and the second doesn't?!

Comment: `password_verify` returns true or false, nothing else. You shouldn't need to use the password for a WHERE clausel if you already confirmed, that everything is ok. You could instead of just fetching one column all columns you need and set what you need if the credentials are correct and otherwise print error and/or redirect.

Comment: You're using `password_hash/verify`: good. You're injecting user-supplied values into your SQL queries: bad...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making life difficult for yourself.

First the result of a `password_verify()` is TRUE or FALSE i.e. verified or not verified. It does not UNHASH the password. Nothing should be able to unhash a hash.

Also you dont need to do 2 seperate calls to get data from your database.

You also dont need to copy the email address from the POST array into a scalar variable.

So this would be a simpler flow for your code

Also you do not really need to filter your users entered password. If it is not right, the `verify_password()` will fail and that is all you need to know.

```
$result = $connect->query("SELECT userid, privilages, password
                           FROM users 
                           WHERE email = '{$_POST['email']}'");

$user = $result->fetch_assoc();

if ( ! password_verify($_POST['password'], $user['password']) ) {
    // show the password error screen
    exit;
} else {
    // save all the SELECTED user info into a sub array of SESSION
    // to be used later
    $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
}
```

> You should really be using parameterised queries instead of injecting POST variables into a query.

```
$stmt= $connect->query("SELECT userid, privilages, password
                           FROM users 
                           WHERE email = ?");

$stmt->bind_param("s", $_POST['email']);
$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result();
$user = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Comment: Thank you :) I know there are a lot of things that I should/could do better, but I haven't been programmer for a very long time. So right now, im doing what I did years ago. I would like to learn PDO and OOP, since what I've heard and read, it should be an "easier" and better approach? Please correct me if im wrong. Thanks again.

Comment: You are not wrong. But it appears your current code is using MYSQLI and not PDO